# Steam download issue

Tags: steam

Normally I let my games on Steam download at night. Recently I bought a game that because of its size I’d have to let download over night. I got the game like 3 days ago and every morning Steam has stopped downloading that game and started to download another instead. Anyone know why it’s doing this?

Comment: what game you trying to download?

Comment: How many games do you have queued up to download...? At some point you should only have the one game to download right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why Steam is doing that, but a solution would be to set the game download to high priority.

Right-click the game in your steam library, then go to properties --> updates, and set "automatic updates" to "high priority"

[image: High priority updates]

Another option would be to go to your downloads tab (view --> downloads) and pause all other updates.

Answer (score 1):

Not all Steam games are hosted on the same server.

If you have multiple games going, and you pause one to try to download another, you may see different download speeds. This means that you're not making the same connection to get the game enough though it is still on Steam.

This means that if one server is particularly overloaded with a popular game, it may occasionally pause. If you have multiple games downloading, it'll simply move on to the next game.

Remove/pause your other games and let Steam download only this one game.